# Python: Mad Libs

Tags: python

Hi I have this project of Mad libs but I don´t know how to make a function that ask the user what level of difficulty between easy, medium or hard they want, and depending on their answer redirect them to the desired level of mad libs. This is what I have so far. Thanks.

```
parts_of_speech_words = ["VERB","PLACE","ADJECTIVE","NOUN","PLURALNOUN","ADVERB"]

level_easy = """I __VERB__ to go to the __PLACE__
             but I don't go in the __ADJECTIVE__
             I am __ADJECTIVE__ of the __NOUN__
             and getting __VERB__ by a __NOUN__."""


level_medium = """Begging to hear __NOUN__
             My ears remain __ADJECTIVE__ 
             __NOUN__ for signs
             my __NOUN__ remain __VERB__
             Yet __NOUN__still VERB."""


level_hard = """I __VERB__ you without __NOUN__
             how, or when, or from where,
             I love you __ADVERB__,
             without __PLURALNOUN__ or pride;
             So I love you because I know
             no other way that this:
             Where I does not VERB, nor you,
             so close that your NOUN
             on my chest is my hand,
             so close that your NOUN close
             as I fall ADJECTIVE."""

greeting = raw_input ("Welcome to mad libs, What's your name? ")
prompt = raw_input ("Select your level: easy, medium or hard: ")

def entry_level_prompt (variable_level):
    easy = level_easy
    medium = level_medium
    hard = level_hard
    for e in variable_level:
        if prompt == easy:
            return level_easy
            print level_easy
        if prompt == medium:
            return level_medium
            print level_medium
        if prompt == hard:
            return level_hard
            print lever_hard
print "Ok %s you chose the %s level" % (greeting , prompt)
print entry_level_prompt (variable_level)

def parts_of_speech (words_string, list_of_part_of_speech):
    for pos in list_of_part_of_speech:
        if pos in words_string:
            return pos
    return None

def play_mad_libs (split_string, list_of_part_of_speech):
    replaced = []
    split_string = split_string.split ()
    for words_string in split_string:
        replacement = parts_of_speech (words_string, list_of_part_of_speech)
        if replacement != None:
            user_input = raw_input ("Type in a: " + replacement + " ")
            words_string = words_string.replace (replacement, user_input)
            replaced.append(words_string)
        else:
            replaced.append(words_string)
    replaced = " ".join(replaced)
    return replaced

print play_mad_libs (entry_level_prompt, parts_of_speech_words)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your code. You are calling `entry_level_prompt(variable_level)` but `variable_level` does not exist outside of the method scope.

To control the difficulty, you can create a method called `get_difficulty()`

```
def get_difficulty():
    choice = ""
    while choice not in ('easy', 'medium', 'hard'):
        choice = raw_input("choose your difficulty: ")
        if choice == "easy":
            return level_easy
        elif choice == "medium":
            return level_medium
        elif choice == "hard":
            return level_hard
        else:
            print("Invalid choice...")
```

Answer (score 1):

You've confused the selector -- "easy", "medium", or "hard" -- with the variable you want to return -- level_easy, level_medium, or level_hard.  You cannot use the variable prompt for both purposes at the same time.

I recommend that you keep variable prompt as you started: it holds the user input.  Then, simply test it and return the needed script:

```
if prompt == "easy":
    return level_easy
elif prompt == "medium"
    return level_medium
elif prompt == "hard"
    return level_hard
else:
    "Please enter easy, medium, or hard for the level."
```